# Instantiating different number of objects per spline

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a spline object that is made up of 3 splines and I want to instantiate an object using the "Evaluate Spline" node along each spline in the list, but I need to feed in the number of instances per spline in the splines list via an integer list. I'm kinda stumped cuz if I had the same number for the splines and the instances per spline, I would have been able to solve this within a single loop, but here I need n number of instances for the first spline, and n number of instances for the second spline and so on. Naturally, I want this system to be adaptive, like if I have 6 splines in a spline object, I will feed in 6 integers to specify the number of instances per spline in the splines list. Hope the explanation was clear enough :-)

Here's a snapshot illustrating what I'm after: [image]

Thank you :)

AJ

Answer (score 1):

[image]

These should work. The one uses the splines points and a multiplier as an input integer for the amount of points to evaluate per spline.
The other uses a integer list you can edit, each input corresponding to a spine in your spine list.

Both of these output a list of locations which can be fed into a **Instancer** node.
A **3d viewer** node can also be handy to see which integer list input corresponds to which spline.